# Как вывести строчку <tr> таблицы, сгенерированной через ng-repeat в модальное окно?

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

### Модальное окно из ng-repeat

Не могу понять, как по клику вывести все значения "td" из "tr" в модальное окно, т.е есть много строк таблицы с различными данными:

---

```
key1: данные1, key2: данные2 ...
```

(1 строка)

---

```
key1: данные3, key2: данные4 ...
```

(2 строка)

---

и т.д. И как по клику, например на первую строку, получить модальное окно с "данные 1" и "данные 2" и т.д. Они сгенерированы через ng-repeat и явно через DOM не получается обратиться, в этом проблема
Попытки записать значение через directive template, не увенчались успехом, передать значение с помощью Jquery в dialog или ng-message так-же.

---

```
<div  class="md-padding dialogdemoBasicUsage" id="popupContainer" ng-cloak="">
    <tr  ng-repeat="mySomeData in someDataStorage | orderBy:'id':sortReverse " ng-click="showAlert($event,someDataStorage[mySomeData])">
         <td>{{mySomeData.key1}}</td>
         <td>{{mySomeData.key2}}</td>
         <td>{{mySomeData.key3}}</td>
         <td>{{mySomeData.key4}}</td> </tr>
</div>
```

---

Контроллер делает get запросы в someDataStorage.json и по ним строит таблицу, а модальное окно выводится через "Angular Alert".

```
  angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog, $mdMedia, $http) {
  $http.get('someDataStorage.json').success(function(data) {
                $scope.someDataStorage = data;
            });

  $scope.showAlert = function($event) {
    $mdDialog.show(
      $mdDialog.alert()
     .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#popupContainer')))
        .clickOutsideToClose(true)
        .title('Модальное окно с информацией из таблицы')
        .textContent("Что-то надо написать")
        .ariaLabel('Alert Dialog Demo')
        .ok('Закрыть')
        .targetEvent($event)
    );
  };
});
```

Comment: если используется ангуляр, лучше использовать ангуляр, а не jquery плагины

Comment: как приведенный код между собой связан? пока это три куска которые никак не связаны

Comment: Подправил, надеюсь код стал понятнее

Comment: Стоит посмотреть справку по используемой библиотеке: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog

Comment: я запутался: в чем именно заключается проблема? что, откуда ты открываешь и где появляется неожиданное поведение?

Comment: Не могу понять, как по клику вывести все значения <td> из <tr> в модальное окно, т.е есть много строк таблицы с различными данными: 
<tr>key1: данные1, key2: данные2 ... </tr> (1 строка)
<tr>key1: данные3, key2: данные4 ... </tr> (2 строка)
и т.д.
И как по клику например на первую строку, получить модальное окно с данные 1 и данные 2 и т.д. Они сгенерированы через ng-repeat и явно через DOM не получается обратиться, в этом проблема

Comment: Это описание перенеси в вопрос. это раз. Тебе и не надо к ним явно через обращаться - это два. Используй ангуляр.

Comment: Подправил, спасибо, буду разбираться дальше

Comment: Все так же бьюсь с этим вопросом, но вроде как решение лежит в  template: и <md-dialog-content>' ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Нужно воспользоваться свойством `templateUrl`, и указать свой шаблон для диалога
2. Передать в контроллер диалога нужные данные используя свойство `locals`

Адаптированный [пример из справки](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog)

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog, $mdMedia) {
  $scope.someDataStorage = [{
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key3: 3
  }, {
    key1: 11,
    key2: 12,
    key3: 13
  }];
  $scope.showAlert = function(ev, data) {
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController,
        locals: {
          data: data
        },
        templateUrl: 'detail.tmpl.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: true
      })
      .then(function(answer) {
        $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
      }, function() {
        $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
      });
  };

});

function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog, data) {
  $scope.data = data;
  $scope.hide = function() {
    $mdDialog.hide();
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $mdDialog.cancel();
  };

  $scope.answer = function(answer) {
    $mdDialog.hide(answer);
  };
}


/**
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be in foundin the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/license.
**/
```

```css
.dialogdemoBasicUsage #popupContainer {
  position: relative;
}
.dialogdemoBasicUsage .footer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.dialogdemoBasicUsage .footer,
.dialogdemoBasicUsage .footer > code {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.dialogdemoBasicUsage button {
  width: 200px;
}
.dialogdemoBasicUsage div#status {
  color: #c60008;
}
.dialogdemoBasicUsage .dialog-demo-prerendered md-checkbox {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
/*
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be in foundin the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/license.
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.0-rc.5/docs.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" class="md-padding dialogdemoBasicUsage" id="popupContainer" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">

  <div class="dialog-demo-content" layout="row" layout-wrap="" layout-margin="" layout-align="center">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>key1</th>
          <th>key2</th>
          <th>key3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="mySomeData in someDataStorage" ng-click="showAlert($event,mySomeData)">
          <td>{{mySomeData.key1}}</td>
          <td>{{mySomeData.key2}}</td>
          <td>{{mySomeData.key3}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="detail.tmpl.html">
    <md-dialog aria-label="Detail" ng-cloak>
      <form>
        <md-toolbar>
          <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <h2>Detail</h2>
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="cancel()">
              <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_close_24px.svg" aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
          </div>
        </md-toolbar>

        <md-dialog-content>
          <div class="md-dialog-content">
            <pre>{{data|json}}</pre>
          </div>
        </md-dialog-content>

      </form>
    </md-dialog>
  </script>
</div>

<!--
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be in foundin the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/license.
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то, как минимум, для передачи данных таблицы в функцию`showAlert` нужно передать `someDataStorage[someData]` вторым аргументом, либо первым, в зависимости от нужды. В итоге `<tr  ng-repeat="mySomeData in someDataStorage | orderBy:'id':sortReverse " ng-click="showAlert($event, someDataStorage[mySomeData])">`.

Comment: идея правильная, реализация ошибочная: `mySomeData` - это не индекс, это объект

Comment: т.е someDataStorage.mySomeData ?

Comment: @ДимаМаруткин, нет, просто `mySomeData`